# Shared Variables not working when section is suppressed in Crystal Reports

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

So I'm trying to make a report using Crystal Reports. I'm making a summarized report based on 2 subreports. To explain it better I have the screenshot below...
[image]

Basically there are 2 subreports in their designated sections. To make it short, each subreport is summing up amounts and passing the total to shared variables. Formula fields
'Total Add' and 'Total Less' contain the sum of amounts from corresponding subreports, afterwhich 'net' formula field is the difference between the 2 sums. I would like to get a report similar to the screenshot below...

[image]

I would like to hide the subreports so I suppressed them, thus only showing GroupFooterSection4. However, suppressing the subreports would yield 0 values for my formula fields. The summing processes don't work if I suppress them. If I don't suppress the subreports I get the correct values but the problem is the subreports show and I want them hidden. How do I go about fixing this issue? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't suppress the subreport. Instead, suppress all the sections inside the subreport.

For the main reports section where the subreport is, you can turn on the option to 'suppress blank section'. You also need to check 'Suppress blank subreport' under format object.